# Error when opening SQLite Connection on C#?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sqlite, memory

I'm trying to connect and select data from a SQLite database table but it's showing me this error in `con.Open()` line:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in SQLite.NET.dll
>
> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt

Here's my code:

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = db.sqlite; Version=3;");
con.Open();

SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("Select * from [user] where login=@login and password=@password", con);

command.Parameters.Add("@login", textBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@password", textBox2.Text);
```

I also added reference to SQLite .dll.

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Why the spaces in the connection string around `=` sign? The Data Source should be `"Data Source=db.sqlite"`. Did you check to see if the file exists?

Comment: yes the file exists in the project file and I also added it as embedded resource, should I remove the spaces from the connection string? I need that file to be referenced to automatically when executing the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you try to embedd your database into your assembly. That is not a good idea since that memory is read only.

Comment: I checked the connection string but still the same error. I'm using Finisar.SQLite namespace. As for the database, I added .sqlite file to the project files and changed the built option as "Embedded resource".
I downloaded those dll file in a .zip file, can you provide me with another link to download them?

Comment: Well, there is your problem. You cannot embed a database, that memory is read only.

Comment: Oh okay i'll change the build option. I'm trying to make the database executable with the application so that if it's executed in a different computer, it will still have access to the database. Before this, I was using SQLServer and changed it to SQLite. 
Will this help me in making the database deployable with the application?

Comment: Just deploy db.sqlite with your executable assembly and that should be fine

Comment: Thank you so much for your help that error stopped showing, but now I get another error of "Valid parameters: Data Source = <database file >..." as if it's not accessing that db.sqlite file . That file is in my project files should I change its location or the connection string?

Comment: According to your connection string db.sqlite should be in the same directory as your executable.

Comment: I put that file with my project files in the application folder and for the option "Copy" I changed it to copy always and it shows in the Debug folder but it still can't access it.